# How to sort li?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
function addWin() {
    const winsList = document.querySelector('.wins__list');
    const inputBet = document.querySelector('input[name="bet"]');
    const inputSum = document.querySelector('input[name="sum"]');
    const btnGetValues = document.querySelector('#btnGetValues');
    const winArray = [];

    function arrayWins(bet, sum, x) {
        winArray.push({bet, sum, x});
    }

    btnGetValues.addEventListener('click', getValues);
    function getValues() {
        const winBet = Number(inputBet.value);
        const winSum = Number(inputSum.value)
        const winX = Number((winSum / winBet).toFixed(2));

        arrayWins(winBet, winSum, winX);

        var winsItem = document.createElement('li');
        winsItem.classList.add('win' , 'wins__item');
        winsList.appendChild(winsItem);
        for(let i = 0; i < winArray.length; i++) {
            winsItem.innerHTML = 
            '<div class="win__char win__bet"> Ставка: ' + winArray[i].bet + '</div>' + 
            '<div class="win__char win__sum"> Выигрыш: ' + winArray[i].sum + '</div>' +
            '<div class="win__char win__x"> X: ' + winArray[i].x + '</div>'
        }

        winArray.sort((min, max) => min.x < max.x ? 1 : -1);

        console.log(winArray);
        
    }
}

addWin();
```

```css
input, button {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
.wins__item {
    display: flex;
}

.win__char {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="bet" placeholder="Ставка" required/>
<input type="text" name="sum" placeholder="Сумма выигрыша" required/>
<button type="button" id="btnGetValues"> Добавить </button>
<ul class="wins__list"></ul>
```

When you enter values ​​into the fields, the data is pushed into an array, in which objects with values ​​are created. These objects are sorted in descending order of the "x" key value. How to apply the same sorting to the generated li elements. So that strings are displayed in the same order as objects in the array?
https://codepen.io/smeecy/pen/OJRNado

```
.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you empty the existing list via `innerHTML=''` that way old data isn't shown. Then you simply move the sort above the loop so that the updated array will be available for the loop, then in the loop itself is where you generate and append the HTML.

```js
function addWin() {
    const winsList = document.querySelector('.wins__list');
    const inputBet = document.querySelector('input[name="bet"]');
    const inputSum = document.querySelector('input[name="sum"]');
    const btnGetValues = document.querySelector('#btnGetValues');
    const winArray = [];

    function arrayWins(bet, sum, x) {
        winArray.push({bet, sum, x});
    }

    btnGetValues.addEventListener('click', getValues);
    
    function getValues() {
        const winBet = Number(inputBet.value);
        const winSum = Number(inputSum.value)
        const winX = Number((winSum / winBet).toFixed(2));

        arrayWins(winBet, winSum, winX);
        
        winArray.sort((min, max) => min.x < max.x ? 1 : -1);
        
        winsList.innerHTML = "";
        
        for(let i = 0; i < winArray.length; i++) {
           winsItem = document.createElement('li');
           winsItem.classList.add('win' , 'wins__item');
           winsList.appendChild(winsItem);
            winsItem.innerHTML = 
            '<div class="win__char win__bet"> Ставка: ' + winArray[i].bet + '</div>' + 
            '<div class="win__char win__sum"> Выигрыш: ' + winArray[i].sum + '</div>' +
            '<div class="win__char win__x"> X: ' + winArray[i].x + '</div>'
        }

        console.log(winArray);
        
    }
}

addWin();
```

```css
input, button {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
.wins__item {
    display: flex;
}

.win__char {
    flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="bet" placeholder="Ставка" required/>
<input type="text" name="sum" placeholder="Сумма выигрыша" required/>
<button type="button" id="btnGetValues"> Добавить </button>
<ul class="wins__list"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!